# How to write select query with EF-TPH class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, table-per-hierarchy

Work on EF-6 mvc5 project.Face problem with table per hierarchy classs.My class structure is bellow.

[image]

Above picture describes in detial class relations.

Want to write a select query which can select my **home**,**room** and there related **devices** with device type, so i write bellow query but it’s not work.

```
var temp=_myHomeRepository.Queryable().Homes
    .include(x=>x.home.room)//work ok
    .include(x=>x.home.room.select(y=>y.devices))//work ok
    .include(x=>x.home.room.select(y=>y.devices.OfType<D-Type-A>().select(z=>z.D-Type-A))).ToList();//generate error
```

Above query show me error message **"The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parameter name: path"**.Tables which have **TPH** relation,how to make navigation property among them.

In this scenario how to  write select query.

Comment: I can't test right now, so I don't want to give a wrong answer. I think you should put the select after the includes. `[...].include(x=>x.home.room.select(y=>y.devices)).select(y=>y.devices).OfType<D-Type-A>().select(z=>z.D-Type-A)))`. I know its still wrong in the select path, but maybe you get the figure

Comment: @ grek40 ,Thanks for your reply,your syntax 50 works well and 50 is not working.Working portion is [...].include(x=>x.home.room.select(y=>y.devices)) and not working portion is select(y=>y.devices).OfType<‌​D-Type-A>().select(z=>z.D-Type-A))),it's show me on y devices not available here only have home information

Comment: Yes, as I thought, I missed part of the select. Basically, you have to repeat the full select path as you have it in your includes. Also, you may want to have all devices in a single list instead of having a list of device lists (thats why I use SelectMany now). `.Include(...).SelectMany(x => x.home.room.devices).OfType<‌​D-Type-A>().Select(x => x.D-Type-A)`

Comment: @ grek40, Try your new syntax it's also show error "DbOfTypeExpression requires an expression argument with a polymorphic result type that is compatible with the type argument."

Comment: @grek40,I modify your some syntax then it's work but it can not load include classes .My modify syntax is [...].Include(x => x.Home).SelectMany(x => x.Home.Rooms).SelectMany(y=>y.SmartDevices).OfType<SmartSwitch>().Select(z=>z.Channels).ToList()

Comment: I think I misunderstood your intention at first... Since you try to load so many nested levels, you should consider to include some layers in separate calls.